# Integrating fb sonar tool with react-native ios project

Tags: ios, react-native

Facebook recently released new tool sonar that is aimed at helping developers to debug their Android / iOS apps.

Its setup consists of 2 steps, downloading a desktop client and setting up SKD.

The SDK bit docs can be found here: https://fbsonar.com/docs/getting-started.html#setup-your-ios-app

There are a lot of pods to install and I believe it assumes swift is used.

I am trying to add this into react-native iOS project, where ObjC is used and some of the packages like Yoga are already used by React, however I don't specify them in my podspec, they come from `node_modules`.

Comment: Weirdly it says it doesn't work with swift:
"Also Sonar doesn't work with swift projects as its written in C++ and had C++ dependencies. But we are working on supporting sonar for swift projects. You can find this issue here"

yet specifies a swift version in the pod file...
Hopefully someone much smarter than me can make a bridging module to the JS code!

Comment: ps, my podfile to include yoga contains the react pods like so:

`
    pod "yoga", :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga"
    pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'BatchedBridge', # Required For React Native 0.45.0+
    'Core',
    'DevSupport'
    # Add any other subspecs you want to use in your project
    ]

`
Sorry can't seem to get the hang of formatting code in the comments here :/

Comment: @SamMatthews Nice spot, I don't think this requires a js bridge, you just pop it in your ios project if it is in Debug / Dev mode and thats it. I'm just not sure how non Swift pod-spec of this would look, they seem to be performing an install step there as well. And ofc, do we need to ad yoga etc.. if we are in react native project.

Comment: yes I'll be very interested to see a successful integration as I definitely want to explore what it can do but am just too busy (and scared) to play around with our podfile etc as you know how cocoapods can be haha! Well I'm honestly not sure about Yoga pod, I vaguely remember I needed to add these in when I started using libraries that required pods in general. It was something I took a bit of objection to at the time as that brings all new potential issues into play... but if it works without that would be ideal